# Wrong subscription expiry date in Android

Tags: android, google-api

I've implemented the subscriptions purchases in my Android app and everything works well except that I don't get a valid expiry date when I verify the status of a subscription. To verify the status of a subscription, I run a cron task on my server (in PHP) with the Android Google API and update my database accordingly.

I receive a JSon response from the Google API which looks like that :

```
Google_Service_AndroidPublisher_SubscriptionPurchase Object
(
    [internal_gapi_mappings:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [autoRenewing] => 1
    [expiryTimeMillis] => 1426085467680
    [kind] => androidpublisher#subscriptionPurchase
    [startTimeMillis] => 1425999079640
    [modelData:protected] => Array
        (
        )

    [processed:protected] => Array
        (
        )
)
```

The "startTimeMillis" gives a correct value (the date when the user purchases a subscription), but the "expiryTimeMillis" is wrong. It should be "startTimeMillis" + 1 month and it gives "startTimeMillis" + exactly 1 day...

What is wrong in your opinion?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! In fact, I've just read that in the docs of the Google API : "Test subscription purchases recur daily, regardless of the product's subscription period."

Comment: Actually I find that the expiryTimeMillis is always just +1day from the time of the query. Do you find the same?

Comment: We are getting the same thing (+1 day from query time).